# Biosphere that simulates sun and moon shifts

Tags: human-biology, biological-networks

Is there an enclosed biosphere that artificially simulates the movement of the sun and moon at increased intervals?

It is known that [the sun and moon](http://www.howplantswork.com/2009/07/25/does-the-moon-affect-plants-part-2-moonlight-and-biorhythms/) alter plant movements therefore I was wondering how far experimentation has gone.  Ideally I am wondering if they have experimented with different speeds of the moon and sun rotation and how it effects plant(and possibly other animal behavior ideas) growth.

Comment: You think about research with different day/night length and the effects on plant/animals?

Comment: @Chris Yes.  Should I give a further explanation?  The moon effects fish migration through the altering of water currents and tides.  In addition the moon alters wolf pack hunting and feeding schedules.  The sun is fairly more obvious and straightforward altering temperatures and altering bird feeding schedules and flight patterns.  There have been a couple studies down on this, but nothing I have seen that demonstrates if the abilities are instinct or learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sun and moon-faking devices exist. Not sure about 'biosphere'. I have personally observed one for honeybees, but that one was fairly crude(bees are dumb). It was just a big room with a hive stand in the middle and a series of fluorescent lights on the ceiling that turned on one after the other. The goal was to mess with bee circadian rhythms and see which genes became more or less expressed in their brains.

There's a slightly more sophisticated thing called a 'grow cabinet'. It has expensive lights to produce sun-spectrum light at direct sunlight intensity and humidity and temperature controls. Scientists use them for crop research when the weather is too random and unpredictable and absolute control is required.

I believe advanced versions simulate moonlight and angle of insolation, but that sort of thing is expensive.

I don't know of any full-sized biodomes with fake celestial objects. The cost of such a biodome would be prohibitive, and the experiments it enabled might be easier(certainly cheaper) to do in a smaller container.